# Determine if path is cross domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url

How can I determine a given virtual path is within the domain during Application_Start?

```
// Cross domain virtual path
"//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"

// In app domain virtual path
"~/scripts/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" is not.
```

**Edit :**

Can I maybe just use

```
VirtualPathUtility.IsRelative()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but you could test and see if the file is actually there:

```
if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)))
{
    //file is on the server
}
```

**UPDATE:** In response to your question if you can use `VirtualPathUtility.IsRelative()`: yes you could. Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.isapprelative%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the specified virtual path
>   is relative to the application.

The difference from what I showed above is `File.Exists` will return false if the file doesn't actually exist. `VirtualPathUtility.IsRelative()` will return true for a path that is relative, whether a file is there or not.

What you use depends on what you are trying to accomplish, which isn't quite clear.

Comment: I thought it was okay to answer your own question but I must've done something wrong because it was deleted. Should I just mark yours as the correct answer?

Comment: Yes it is ok to answer your own question. I think what you posted though just asked a new question and didn't answer your current one. I think what you were posing was a good question and should be asked. As for accepting answers, that is up to you to determine what answer best addresses your question

Comment: I ended up using VirtualPathUtility as @MikeSmithDev verified for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

Because there is no path during Application_Start

Application_Start is triggered when the application starts before and page is processed and especially before any HTML is sent.

As incidentally the path you are talking about is and has to be part of the HTML output.... which is in a View.... this is very very very very very very early late in the processing.

For that you ffirst need to identify the view which needs running a control which needs analyzoing and routing a request which needs having a started app - and that last part, is where you want to know the output.

Comment: The paths I'm talking about are provided in code... ie. StyleBundle/ScriptBundle

Comment: @GoClimbColorado Well, its your code. I'm guessing you know what the path is when you code it in there and whether or not it is relative. Adding some details about what you are trying to do in bundling may help with answers.

Comment: So? Post App_Start go through all the scriptsbundles and get the files and check whether they start with the correct string or not. Did you try that?